# Convert a comma-separated string to an array and back and deleting array elements with onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have an HTML document. There are 2 fields:

- First one is an hidden input field (with a pre selected value)
- The other is an empty text input field. It displays the current value of the first one with jQuery.

Between that 2 fields, I have 9 buttons with different texts inside them.

With jQuery, when I click on a button it add his text in the visible field (separated by a coma) and it adds to himself an `enabled` class. This works.

When I click on the same button, the class is removed (this works).

**What is not working:**
I would like at the same time it removes his name from the field (with a coma) I With jQuery / JavaScript I have tried to convert with `split()` each name in the field (coma separated) to an array, to easily delete one of them when needed with `splice()`.

**What I haven done yet:**
I need to convert-it back to a coma separated string, replacing the existing string value in the field ( I haven done this yet). I am not far.

My code on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/1r56y297/2/)

How can I achieve this?

My code in here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ($('.subscribe-text').val() == ''){
     $('.subscribe-text').val($('.subscribe-text-get').val()+',')
    }


    $('.subscribe-button').click(function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('enable'))
        {
         $('.subscribe-text').val($('.subscribe-text').val()+$(this).html()+',');
         $(this).addClass('enable');
        } 
        else if($(this).hasClass('enable'))
        //
        // I would like to remove the name in the field
        // when a button is clicked and has 'enable' class
        //
        {
         var myArray = new Array();
         var myString = $('.subscribe-text').val();
         myArray = myString.split(",");
         var myItem = $(this).html()+' ';
         var indexPos = myArray.indexOf(myItem);
         if(indexPos != -1)
            {
         myArray = myArray.splice(indexPos, 1);
   }
         $('.subscribe-text').val(myArray);
         $(this).removeClass('enable');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.subscribe-button {
    background-color:#ddd
}
#buttons_x3 {
    width:500px;
}
.subscribe-text {
    width:100%;
    font-size:9px;
}
.subscribe-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center; 
    padding:3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 20px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <input type="hidden" class="subscribe-text-get" name="my_field_name" value="woo-multi-1">
</div>
<br>
<div id="buttons_x3">
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-3</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-multi-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-multi-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-3</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-special</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <input type="text" class="subscribe-text" name="my_field_name" value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of a few things here:

1) Every time you click a button you are creating a new array with one long string inside.

2) Splice returns the value of the removed item, so each time a button is clicked you are setting the array string to be the item that you just removed.

Instead, initialize the array outside of your click function, and add each new item to the end. Set the value of the input with the toString() method. This will preserve the array of remaining values and their order.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var myArray = [];
    
    if ($('.subscribe-text').val() == ''){
     myArray[0] = $('.subscribe-text-get').val();
     $('.subscribe-text').val( myArray.toString() );
    }
    
    var $item, length;
    
    $('.subscribe-button').click(function(){
    
     length = myArray.length;
    
        if(!$(this).hasClass('enable')) {
    
            $item = $(this).html();
            myArray[length] = $item;
    
            $('.subscribe-text').val( myArray.toString() );
            $(this).addClass('enable');
        } 
        else if($(this).hasClass('enable')) {
            
            var myItem = $(this).html();
            var indexPos = myArray.indexOf(myItem);
            if(indexPos != -1) {
             myArray.splice(indexPos, 1);
            }
    
            $('.subscribe-text').val( myArray.toString() );
            $(this).removeClass('enable');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.subscribe-button {
    background-color:#ddd
}
#buttons_x3 {
    width:500px;
}
.subscribe-text {
    width:100%;
    font-size:9px;
}
.subscribe-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center; 
    padding:3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 20px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <input type="hidden" class="subscribe-text-get" name="my_field_name" value="woo-multi-1">
</div>
<br>
<div id="buttons_x3">
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-single-3</a>
<a class="subscribe-button enable">woo-multi-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-multi-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-1</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-2</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-top-3</a>
<a class="subscribe-button">woo-special</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <input type="text" class="subscribe-text" name="my_field_name" value>
```

Here is my code on a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/1r56y297/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I tried to fork your fiddle from the link in your original post - but it was a 404. Here is a link to the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jveens/6fLgfk9o/8/). Hope it helps!

Comment: I just added an update also. woo-multi-1 must have the enable class set initally.

Comment: I updated my answer above. Just add the enable class to the button that corresponds to the preselected value.